# Converting string into TextView?

Tags: android, arraylist

Have a look at this code:

```
ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);

TextView idText = new TextView(this);
idText.setText(row.get(0).toString());
tableRow.addView(idText);

TextView storeText = new TextView(this);
idText.setText(row.get(1).toString());
tableRow.addView(storeText);

TextView maggiText = new TextView(this);
idText.setText(row.get(2).toString());
tableRow.addView(maggiText);
```

I have to manually create a `TextView`, set it to some string and then pass it. Is there a way by which I can directly pass the string to row that can be put in a `for` loop?

I am looking for this approach for scalability issues.

Comment: Sounds like an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) is what you need. You can overwrite `getView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

///you did mistake while copy paste

//idText using in all Tv

let do it as below

```
TextView idText = new TextView(this);
        idText.setText(row.get(0).toString());
        tableRow.addView(idText);

        TextView storeText = new TextView(this);
        storeText.setText(row.get(1).toString());
        tableRow.addView(storeText);

        TextView maggiText = new TextView(this);
        maggiText.setText(row.get(2).toString());
        tableRow.addView(maggiText);
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList row = data.get(position);

```
for(int i=0; i<row.size(); i++)
{
    TextView text= new TextView(this);
    idText.setText(row.get(i).toString());
    tableRow.addView(idText);
}
```

Comment: you arent creating three components in a row, instead you are creating a single textview, and appending three strings to it.