# How to add onclick to the text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-widget

I am displaying event names which from a database and adding them to a `Layout`.Now i want to open another layout which contains the details of a particular Event which i have clicked.How do i add `onclick` to a text which i have displayed? I want to make a text clickable.

```
package com.example.desisquarea;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FullDetails extends ListActivity  {
     //LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

    //DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView lv;
    //RECORDING HOW MANY TIMES THE BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED
    int clickCounter=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_details);
       adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
         Log.v("hiiii", "1@@@@ ");
         lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.layout.listView1);
         Log.v("hiiii", "2i@@@@ ");
         fullItems(null);


    }
    //ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray all=new JSONArray();
    String size;
    //METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
    public void fullItems(View v) {
        String result = "";
         InputStream is=null;
        //the year data to send
     //   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));

        //http post
        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://motal.com/and/events.jsp");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                     is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    size=json_data.getString("size");

                   for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(size);j++){

                      // Log.v("JSONObject", "JSONObject @@@"+json_data.getJSONArray("res"+j));
                      all=json_data.getJSONArray("res"+j);
                     listItems.add("ID"+all.get(0));
                    listItems.add("\n Venue"+all.get(1));
                   listItems.add(" Price:"+all.get(2));

                      //listItems.add(all.get(0)+" \n venue:"+all.get(1)+" Price:"+all.get(3));
                     lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
                   }

                }

        }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }





        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

activity_full_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Log message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.desisquarea/com.example.desisquarea.FullDetails}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Comment: You can set a listener for textview.

Comment: Read up on this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226699/how-to-make-text-view-clickable-in-android) previous question.Explains pretty much everything you need to know about making texts clickable in Android

Comment: what do you want? Is that ListView or TextView?

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for your replys. In above i am adding only text to layout.how can i convert text into text view?

Comment: did you get it? can you explain what is all and listItems

Comment: @anuruddhika it is `JSONarray`

Comment: to remove this exception change @android:id/listView1 this as like this @id/android:list

Comment: @anuruddhika Thanks for your reply's.At last its working.Another guy as given what the error i am doing..

Comment: so did you get the values?

Answer (score 1):

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In above i am adding only text to layout.how can i convert text into text view?

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple as this:

```
txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your reply.In above i am adding text initially to ArrayList and then adding to layout can't i convert text into `textview` while adding to `arraylist`

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple,do it like that:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Codes for action
        }
    });
```

**Updated**
[Converting string into TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793303/converting-string-into-textview)

```
TextView idText = new TextView(this);
    idText.setText(row.get(0).toString());
    tableRow.addView(idText);

    TextView storeText = new TextView(this);
    storeText.setText(row.get(1).toString());
    tableRow.addView(storeText);

    TextView maggiText = new TextView(this);
    maggiText.setText(row.get(2).toString());
    tableRow.addView(maggiText);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In above i am adding only text to layout.how can i convert text into text view?

Answer (score 0):

Set **onclickListener** to your `TextView`.

Just like this:-

```
TextView = textView (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEW_ID); 
textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set ArrayList to ListView like this.

```
private ListView lv;
```

In onCreate method

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

change this line `listItems.add(all.get(0)+" \n venue:"+all.get(1)+" Price:"+all.get(3));` like this.

```
listItems.add("ID"+all.get(0));
listItems.add("Venue"+all.get(1));
......................... etc
```

Then add to addapter

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
     listItems );

     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

After that you can `set OnItemClickListner` like this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Put your custom code here
        }
 });
```

Add this to activity_full_details.xml

```
<ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView1"
         android:layout_width="288dp"
         android:layout_height="330dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="62dp" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In above i am adding only text to layout.how can i convert text into text view?

Comment: In above i am adding text initially to `ArrayList` and then adding to layout cant i add this `text.setText("your text")` while adding to `arrylist`

Comment: aha.. you are using ArrayList then you should add it into listView

Comment: what do u want to display only one element or more elements?

Comment: In present layout many elements.In another layout only one element after `onclick` of text

Comment: still showing error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`  i placed my full code updated above.I am getting error at `  lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: you should add ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
     listItems );
this befor the lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: did you add ListView to xml?

Comment: already i used     `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;` `adapter` in my `onCreate(Bundle icicle)` method so i used ` lv.setAdapter(adapter);`. No i have not added `listview` to xml

Comment: then how you add data to listView?

Comment: i added xml code and change this lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: yes i mentioned `Listview` in `.xml` but still i am getting error. I mentioned my `activity_full_details.xml` above.showing same error `runtime exception`

Comment: i mentioned my log message in above

Comment: you added like this ne (android.R.layout.listView1); you should remove this android world.(R.layout.listView1); like this in onCreate